# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `children' for nil:NilClas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Hello i have an Rspec Test im tring to do for an User controller index action. For user authentication i coded it myself and not using any gems.

I get this error when truing to run the test. I looked up all solutions and nothing worked.

```
  2) UsersController GET #index redirects visitor
     Failure/Error: user_logged_in
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the Test.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  let!(:users) do
    users = []
    3.times { users << create(:user) }
    users
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    before  do
      user_logged_in
      create(users)
    end

    it "user renders template and shows users" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      expect(assigns(:users)).to eq(users)
    end

    it "redirects visitor" do
      get :index
      it { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is rails_helper

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require "shoulda/matchers"

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

def admin_logged_in
  visit login_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: admin.email
  fill_in 'Password', with: admin.password
  click_button 'Log In'
end

 def user_logged_in
  visit login_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
  click_button 'Log In'
end
```

Comment: Please show your `index` method and the full error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete code it is difficult to judge. 
One thing that comes to my mind, I think you misuse the `it {}` syntax. Why don't you rewrite it as

```
it "redirects visitor" do
  get :index
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```